# How to Mysql SELECT by month

Tags: mysql

let's just say I have a data table like this:

```
  DATE               ID
---------------------------
 2019-01-01           1
 2019-02-01           2
 ......               3
 2019-12-01           4
 2018-01-01           5
 2018-02-01           6
 2017-01-01           7
 2017-02-01           8
```

and I want to display them to something like this:

```
  DATE               ID
---------------------------
 2019-01-01           1
 2018-01-01           5
 2017-01-01           7
```

**What I have tried**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATEPART(month, mydate_field) = 01
```

**I also tried another one as below**:

```
DATEPART(month, mydate_field) = 1
```

/

```
DATEPART(month, mydate_field) = '01'
```

/

```
DATEPART(month, mydate_field) = '1'
```

/

```
DATENAME(month, mydate_field) = 'January'
```

---

is there anything else?

because none of the above works

Comment: The first think you should learn is to figure out which dbms you are using. Using SQL Server date functions on MySQL will definitely give you no result.

Comment: it seems so. I need to learn the basics for this, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mysql you could use MONTH

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MONTH(date) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATEPART` is an [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) function. For [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), you could use [`month`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(mydate_field) = 1
```